# Check time of existing PendingIntent in AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Is it possible to query the Android AlarmManager for the time of the next alarm for a given PendingIntent?  I know I can cancel one using the .cancel(PendingIntent) function, and I can update one using .set(), but is it possible to "query" one?  I use something like this to see if one is already scheduled:

```
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

If sender == null, then one is already scheduled.  I'd really like to know "for what time?" if possible.

I know I could save this in a database or other location, when I set it, but I'd really like query "the official source" to be sure.  Possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to query the Android AlarmManager for the time of the next alarm for a given PendingIntent?

Unfortunately, no. 'AlarmManager' is a write-only interface.